# C# Entity Framework 6 - How to handle multiple schemas that have same table names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I'm using C# Entity Framework 6 and I have a database with multiple schemas, in those schemas I have tables with the same names. For example:

1. Rates.Hotel
2. Availability.Hotel

I have a single project for all of my database objects with this structure:

```
Project Name = Storm.API.Data
In this project I have folders with the schema names: "Availability", "Rates".
In each folder I have the proper 'edmx' file.
```

When I run my project I'm getting this error:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 

The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM 
type 'Hotel'. Previously found CLR type 'Storm.API.Data.Rates.Hotel', 
newly found CLR type 'Storm.API.Data.Availability.Hotel'.
```

The only solution I came up with is to separate the schemas to different project, but since I have more than 2 schemas I don't want to create so many project just for that.

Is there another solution that will enable me to have all schemas under the same project without this error ?

Comment: You can edit the Entity Type name on the model browser for each schema. So you have the Type Availability_Hotel on Availability schema and Rates_Hotel on Rates schema.

Comment: I think having separate projects is a good solution, since having different schema is defining your domain and it's better to make this domain separation clear by having separate projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Give each of them a different class name in your code
2. Use 2 different DbContext classes, with a different namespace for the entities. Whether you put this in another project is up to you, but not required.
3. Not sure if this will work, but worth a shot: Make a namespace for every schema and have everything in 1 DbContext.

Comment: 1. It is a bad idea to manually change class name on an auto generated code since it will be lost when updating the model.

2. Using 2 DbContext in the same didn't work.

3. This is what I did in the first place.